# ngIf with ngAnimate - duplicated HTML content during the animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I try to do simple angular animation. But I have a problem, when I'm clicking fast on buttons (before animation is finished), content containers are created that many times as I clicked...

How to prevent this situation? I want to stop animation after click and then start animation on the same object not on the new one?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cc28p39L/6/)

HTML

```
 <div ng-app="test">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="TestController as tCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">                
                <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tCtrl.tt = 1"> 1 </a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tCtrl.tt = 2"> 2 </a>
            </div>
        </div>       
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 animate-if" ng-if="tCtrl.tt === 1">Chosen = 1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 animate-if" ng-if="tCtrl.tt === 2">Chosen = 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate']);


app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    this.tt = 1;
});
```

CSS

```
 .animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {    
     -webkit-transition: opacity 5.2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 5.2s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity 5.2s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 5.2s ease-in-out;  
 }
 .animate-if.ng-enter,
 .animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
     z-index: 0;    
     opacity: 0;
 }

 .animate-if.ng-leave,
 .animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
     z-index: 1;
     opacity: 1;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

I did change code to use `ngRoutes` and `ngView` instead of `ngIf` but behavior of `ngAnimate` is the same.
I think it can be an error in Angular because in console I have error `undefined in not a function` in angular-animate.js at line 1348 which contains `operation.cancel()` and is a part of:

```
  forEach(animationsToCancel, function(operation) {
       operation.cancel();
  });
```

Full problem you can see **[here](http://demo3.grafofaktura.pl/#/dashboard)** when you will click on the left menu 'Dashboard' and 'Users' fast.

**EDIT 2:**

Solution which I am using now:

```
 this.fn_change_view = function (str_view, $event) {
        if (!this.contentStopAnim) {
            this.contentStopAnim = true;
            this.active_view = str_view;
            $timeout(function () {
                template.contentStopAnim = false;
            }, 360);
        } else {
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
```

I am preventing change location href before animation finish but it is not a solution which I am happy about...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way to avoid that (although I'd love if someone prove is not true), `ng-animate` takes care that the element animated is visible for the whole time of animation, if the animation takes 10seconds you will have duplicated elements

Comment: I did change everything to use ngRoutes to change ngView but effect is sadly exactly the same. Is that min Google doesn't create ngAnimate support to animate transitions between views?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations if you go to section `Which directives support animations?` you will see that `ngView` is supported as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` and keyframes to animate. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XigpyjFpeWn8UZ2TeY6?p=preview).

Assign the css events.

```
.ng-hide-add {
  animation:0.1s keyFrameLeave ease; 
}

.ng-hide-remove { 
  animation:0.5s keyFrameEnter ease; 
}
```

Register the keyframes

```
@keyframes keyFrameEnter {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0,100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes keyFrameLeave {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Your html will look like this:

```
<button ng-click="front = !front">click to animate</button>
<div ng-show="front">Displayed</div>
```

Your js

```
$scope.front = false;
```